# How to work on dev branch but keep master as default clone branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I have a local repository I use to develop some feature.
I would like to share that feature while also continuing development on it.
For that I want to have a development branch.

I want to allow people to clone my local repo and receive the master branch by default, instead of having to explicitly ask for it, while I have the repo checked out to the development branch.

i.e. allow people to "git clone /sapir/repo/.git" and receive the master branch
even though /sapir/repo is actually checked out on the development branch at that moment.

is there a way to achieve this without keeping a second copy of the repository for myself?

Comment: Which branch you have checked out locally has no impact on which is the default branch for people cloning the repo.

Comment: I guess you can regard /sapir/repo as the remote in this case
I work directly on the remote so I called it a local repo, my bad.
Is there a way to keep the remote checked out on the dev branch, but have the default clone branch be master, that's the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  But you've set up an odd situation:

- You have naive users, who are not aware that when they run `git clone`, *they* are choosing *which branch to have their Git create*.<sup>1</sup>  Without an explicit choice, they are choosing to have their Git create the branch that your Git recommends.
- You are (or are trying to be, at least) a sophisticated user who is aware of how `git clone` works and hence the fact that, if the person running `git clone` uses neither `-n` (to avoid creating a branch at all) nor `-b` (to choose what to create), the person running `git clone` will pick up a recommendation from your own Git.  Your own Git recommends whichever branch is the *current branch* in your work-tree, or, if this Git repository is bare, the one that would be current: that is, whatever name is stored in `HEAD`.

As a sophisticated user, though, you should already know that Git:

- can use hard links locally, or use `--reference` and the alternates mechanism to share object storage;
- should have a bare repository to receive `git push` directives;
- and therefore, has no need to have any active work-tree, so that you can store anything you like in the `HEAD` of this bare repository.

Being aware of these things, you would just make a bare repository, then clone it locally and/or using `--reference` and work in the clone and not ask this question in the first place.   If you have some special and complicated reason not to use a bare repository, you can also use `git worktree add`, provided your Git version is at least 2.5 (preferably at least 2.15 to avoid some tricky bugs in `git worktree`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that `git clone` copies ***all*** *commits*,<sup>2</sup> but ***no*** *branches*.  Having copied the commits, the last step of `git clone`—unless inhibited via `-n`—is to run a `git checkout`, and that *creates* a *new* branch.  The fact that this new branch generally has the same name as a branch name in the source of the clone is interesting and useful, but not particularly *important* since the new clone is a separate repository and thus does not *need* to use the same names.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, it copies all commits that are *reachable* from all the names that will wind up in the new clone: remote-tracking names and tag names, mostly.  With various options, such as `--single-branch` and/or `--no-tags`, you can choose which of these names will appear in the clone.  You can also create a *shallow clone* with `--depth` or `--shallow-since` and similar options, to exclude some commits and related objects.  Quite recently, you can enable *promissory packs* and thereby create a *partial clone*, though this needs a lot of work to make it practical for more users.